# php persistent connections storage?

Tags: php

I am reading about persistent connections and I learned that `php` once make a connection, it stores it as a link so that execution of the same script would use the same connection rather than opening the new one. 
Ok, so all is good.

Questions is

1. How it is possible for PHP to keep connections alive when it terminates after execution.
2. Where, in which directory/cache/database, can I see these connections (out of curiosity)?

Please consider nginx/php-fpm architecture.

Comment: What type of connection do you have in mind here?

Comment: @arkascha : I am simply asking, can i know where PHP stores persistent connections so that they can be reused. Say I connect to MongoDB using MongoClient PHP Class. It says, it utilizes persistent connections, out of curiosity, where does this class stores these persistent connections. In other words, how do I verify if MongoClient is making persistent connections.

Comment: Ah, so you are talking about connections from php to some resource, for example a database server. There are other types too, that is why I ask. Like the persistent "keep alive" mode in the http protocol. Or socket connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please consider nginx/php-fpm architecture.

Excellent!

> 1. How it is possible for PHP to keep connections alive when it terminates after execution.

PHP doesn't terminate in this case. The child process, the one handling actual request, it doesn't exit (unless configured to do so). Therefore, if it didn't exit, it keeps the connection(s) open if possible (this is simplified *yes* type of answer).

> 2. Where, in which directory/cache/database, can I see these connections (out of curiosity)?

You can't see it in the directory. You can see it using `lsof`. Find the `pid` of any of child process(es) via `ps aux | grep php`.

Use `lsof -p process_id` and you can see open file descriptors. Among them, there will be connections towards MySQL etc.

If you're using MySQL and you want to see connections that are established, you can execute `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`.

Comment: Thanks, I verified answer of the second questions using lsof. I can see TCP connections of MongoDB. I still didnt understand the first part. Can you please elaborate more. Like when nginx pass request to php-fpm process. it executes the php script then what happened next ?

Comment: Ok, the child process spawned by `php-fpm` receives request, finds all the `.php` files it has to work with, parses them, stores them to opcache, executes the code it has to and sends the response back to `nginx` but it **does not terminate** at this point. The process stays alive. The resources don't get cleaned up (again, this is simplified). Thus, when next request comes in, the code has been parsed and can be pulled from opcache, certain connections have been established so no handshake is required and you get a speedup on subsequent requests handled by `php-fpm` child processes.

Comment: Thanks, it is now clear. So basically, it is php-fpm process itself which parse, compile,execute, keep database connections for future used and capture output to return back to nginx. Initially, I used to think, php-fpm process launch another php-interpreter which does all parsing,compiling and excution work, which completely confused me. Thanks

Comment: `php-fpm` launches these processes. When they exit, `php-fpm` receives a signal that something happened to the child. This is also the reason why `php-fpm` doesn't work on windows - windows doesn't implement POSIX compliant API for process control, thus you can't do the whole parent-child thing . It acts as a supervisor, and can boot up a new process, keeping the whole thing working forever. `php-fpm` is, as its name says, the **manager** and child processes are the ones that do the heavy work. It'd be quite tricky to share connections between child processes. It's easier if each has its own.

Comment: Thanks @Mjh for clarification

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!